# how do i verify the button is enabled or not in selenium java code for below element

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, dom

Element when enabled

```html
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-binding" data-ng-hide="config.enabled" data-ng-click="enable(config.id, config.name)" has-permission="UPDATE_CONFIGURATION">Enable</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-show="config.enabled" data-ng-click="disable(config.id, config.name)" has-permission="UPDATE_CONFIGURATION">Disable</button>
</td>
```

element when disabled

```hmtl
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-hide="config.enabled" data-ng-click="enable(config.id, config.name)" has-permission="UPDATE_CONFIGURATION">Enable</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ng-binding" data-ng-show="config.enabled" data-ng-click="disable(config.id, config.name)" has-permission="UPDATE_CONFIGURATION">Disable</button>
</td>
```

Above you can see two button elements in `td` tag, but only one button is visible in the front page either enable or disable.

How can I verify that in selenium code the button is enabled or disabled?

I am not able to find the right way to figure out which button out of the two is visible in selenium code, would appreciate the help.